# DivShot: When Exporting Bootstrap/Retriever Layout Top Menu Bar White

Tags: divshot

When you export a template using the Retriever/Bootstrap template, the top menu bar is white. The background stitch.png doesn't display. You can't read the menu bar. How do I get the css to point to the stitch.png file?

Thanks